# radio button, reference external document

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, checked

Not sure how to explain this but I'm trying to open a new window and at the same time setting a particular radio button on the opened page.

Contact-us.php (my page to Open)

```
<form name="f2" method="post" action="send_form_email3.php" id="Homeform1" onsubmit="return checkEmail(this)">

<input type="radio" name="package" value="Option1"> Basic 
<input type="radio" name="package" value="Option2"> Silver
<input type="radio" name="package" value="Option3"> Gold
<input type="radio" name="package" value="Custom"> Custom
```

This is the page with the button

Home.php

```
<a href="javascript:win1=window.open('contact-us.php'); setCheckedValue(win1.document.forms['f2'].elements['package'], 'Option2');" id="link2" class="links"></a>
```

and this is the JS file

```
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

}

So it works for the same page, if I put my form on the same page as the button (home.php)

However currently all the code does is open a new page!(Contact-us.php)

I'm not 100% sure this can be done but my ultimate goal is to open a new page, with the radio option already selected when the user clicks an image.

P.S this is not the full code as I only posted the partd I feel relevant.

Comment: Your code would work with a modal div or a floating div, how about that instead. Popups are blocked by most browsers anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to `contact-us.php?checkedValue=...` and read them either with php or Javascript.

Or you can have a Javascript code inside `contact-us.php` that will read some value in the parent window, something like `parent.yourGlobalObject.checkedValue`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, @Mic I never really thought about passing a parameter but now realizing it would likely work. Anyways I decided to use modal divs as suggested by Drew which took no time to work.